# Asking for a combinatorial proof of a binomial-sum

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, elementary-proofs

> **QUESTION.** Is there a combinatorial proof of the below identity?
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2^{2k}}{2k+1}\frac{\binom{2n}n}{\binom{2k}k}=2^{2n}-\binom{2n}n.$$

**REMARK.** There are many other proofs (algebraic, analytic, etc).

Comment: Dividing by $\binom{2n}{n}$ and applying the natural inductive argument reduces this to the identity $(\star) \, \binom{2(n+1)}{n+1}(n+1) = \binom{2n}{n} 2(2n+1)$. So perhaps an easier problem is first finding a combinatorial proof of $(\star)$.

Comment: @Ofir Gorodetsky: the identity $(\star)$ is also the inductive step for $4^n=\sum_{i}{2i \choose i}{2n-2i\choose n-i } $, which has a story of combinatoric interpretations (Richard Stanley in *Enumerative Combinatorics* quotes a  couple of papers, and there are also some questions on it here on MO).

Comment: An equivalent form of $(\star)$ is ${2n+2\choose n+1}{n+1\choose2}={2n \choose n}{2n+1\choose2}$, which is also tempting.

Comment: Since $\binom{2n}{n}/\binom{2k}{k}$ is typically not an integer, maybe this is not the best form to start with when asking for a combinatorial proof? Particularly since I interpret this as asking for a bijective proof, for preference. (I'm sure you can easily prove the identity using generating functions, or by the inductive approach indicated in Ofir Gorodetsky's comment.)

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky we may count such things: divide $2n+2$ students to two groups each consistent of $n+1$ students and choose a leader in each group. If we start with choosing the division by groups, this gives ${2(n+1)\choose n+1}(n+1)^2$ variants. If we start with choosing two leaders, this gives $(2n+2)(2n+1){2n\choose n}$. So we get your $(\star)$ multiplied by $n+1$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Of course (I forgot to mention that). But what I'd really like to learn is a method to make an interpretation of the identity $\sum_i{2i \choose i }{2n-2i\choose n-i}=4^n$ (or of the OP's) out of the natural interpretation of $(\star)$.

Comment: Maybe divide through by $\binom{2n}{n}$ and think of a probabilistic argument involving, say, increasing binary trees vs. increasing ternary trees? This is very half-baked, though.